# Is there an official facebook messenger chatbot NodeJS API?

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-messenger, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I see a lot of node.js package to integrate messenger chatbot.
I would like to know what is the best solution / package ?
Is there a recommandation provided by Facebook ?

Answer (score 0):

See the FB Node.js Messenger Quick Start Guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/guides/quick-start